# Rails: Add form from different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, associations, partial

In my rails app, i have a project model which can have many project messages.

`project has_many project_messages`

In `projects/show.html.erb`, I would like to display all project messages for that project but also create new project messages from this view.
Currently, I am not able to create new project messages from this view.

I have reviewed a number of links but none work for me 
[Adding Form For Different Model In Same View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793334/adding-form-for-different-model-in-same-view),
[Rails: Show form from different model in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188999/rails-show-form-from-different-model-in-a-view)

My `projects/show.html.erb` file references as follows:

```
<div>
 <% render partial: 'project_messages/form', :object => @project_message %>
</div>
```

In the `projects_controller.rb` file I have included the following:

```
  def show
    @project_message = ProjectMessage.new
  end
```

&

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :phase_id, :RAGStatus, :currentpphase_id,  :project_messages_attributes => [:pMessage, :user_id, :project_id])
end
```

And in the `project.rb` file I have the following code also:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_messages
```

project_messages/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: project_message, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if project_message.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(project_message.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project_message from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% project_message.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<%= form.label :pMessage %>
<%= form.text_field :pMessage, id: :project_message_pMessage, :class => 'au-input au-input--full au-input--h65', placeholder: 'Type a message' %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The project_messages form partial does not render so I cannot add a new message from this view.

Error:

```
undefined local variable or method `project_message' for #<#<Class:0x007f5455ced910>:0x007f5459ef8a30>
Did you mean?  @project_message
```

When I add @project_message to the partial, it does not render.

Comment: Please, provide error text, partial 'project_messages/form' to truly complete question.

Comment: What is `partial 'project_messages/form' `? What exactly do you mean by "I am not able to create new project messages from this view"? Is there an error? What is the error?

Comment: @Tom Lord - apologies I am new to rails! More detail now added.

Comment: @Leo - error message and partial added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when rendering a partial like:

```
<% render partial: 'form', object: @project_message %>
```

Because you are passing the `@project_message` as the specially-named `object` parameter, this creates a special variable with the name of the partial - in this case, `form`.

Therefore in the partial, you could reference this variable:

```
<%= form_with(model: form, local: true) do |form| %>
```

...However, in this case, it doesn't really make sense to call the local variable `form`! So I would be inclined to use whatever name you're passing it in as - for example, you could do:

```
<% render partial: 'form', project_message: @project_message %>
```

And then in the partial:

```
<%= form_with(model: project_message, local: true) do |form| %>
```

For more info, see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

Comment: Thank you! Thanks working now, using `<%= render partial: 'project_messages/form', locals: { project_message: @project_message } %>` - is there any way of stopping the redirect after it created the message?

Comment: @EvaB11 That's a separate question, but it sounds like you want to make this an asynchronous form submission - in which case you need to add `remote: true`. There's loads of information about this online, e.g. [this](http://www.korenlc.com/remote-true-in-rails-forms/)

Comment: great thanks for your help! I have opened a new question for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441779/rails-using-remote-true-to-stop-page-refresh/51443132#51443132)

Answer (score 0):

In `project_messages/_form.html.erb`, this line:

```
<%= form_with(model: project_message, local: true) do |form| %>
```

Should be changed to this:

```
<%= form_with(model: object, local: true) do |form| %>
```

You assigned a local variable `object` to a partial, so you should use it.

Also, partials may also be called this way:

```
<% render partial: 'form', object: @project_message %>
```