# Rails: Using remote: true to stop page refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, page-refresh

I have a `projects/show.html.erb` page. A `project has_many project_messages` and from the `projects/show.html.erb` page, a user can create a new `project_message` successfully, however, when the new `project_message` is created through a `_form`partial, the page refreshes.

I want to use :remote => true to add `project_messages` to the project without having to refresh the page. 
Please see the code I used below. This does not work and the page still refreshes. I am new to rails so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please see the code for each file below

In `projects/show.html.erb`to display the project_message and create a new project_message, I have the following code which is successful:

```
<div class="au-chat au-chat--border">
   <div class="au-message-list">
         <% @project.project_messages.each do |project_message| %>
         <%= render partial: 'project_messages/project_message', locals: { project_message: project_message } %>
         <% end %><br>
   </div>


   <div class="au-chat-textfield">, 
         <%= render partial: 'project_messages/form', locals: { project_message: @project_message } %>                                                 
   </div>
</div>
```

In the `project_messages_controller.rb` file the create method is as follows, I have added `format.js   { }`

```
  def create
    @project_message = ProjectMessage.new(project_message_params)
    @project_message.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    @project_message.project_id = current_user.team.project_id if current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_message.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project_message.project }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project_message }
        format.js   { }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project_message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The `project_message` `_form` partial then includes the `:remote => true`

```
<%= form_with(model: project_message, local: true, :remote => true) do |form| %>
  <% if project_message.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(project_message.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project_message from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% project_message.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<%= form.text_field :pMessage, id: :project_message_pMessage, :class => 'au-input au-input--full au-input--h65', placeholder: 'Type a message' %>
  <div class="actions" >
    <%= form.submit "Send" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I then created a new `create.js.erb` file in views/project_messages/create.js.erb and added the following code:

```
# confirm file called
console.log('create.js.erb file');

# add new comment to end of comments section
$("#project_message").append("<%= j render(@project_message) %>");
```

With the code above, the page still refreshes. 
When I remove  `local: true` from the `project_message` `_form` partial, it does not refresh and creates the model but the `projects/show.html.erb` view is not updated!

I used the following link [here](http://www.korenlc.com/remote-true-in-rails-forms/) and also other posts on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

respond_to do |format|
 format.js { render 'project_messages/create.js'}
end

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work. The model is still created but the view does not refresh.   The following from rails server: `(14.0ms)  commit transaction
  Rendering project_messages/create.js.erb
  Rendered project_messages/_project_message.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered project_messages/create.js.erb (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 36ms (Views: 9.5ms | ActiveRecord: 16.2ms)`

Comment: @EvaB11 console.log('create.js.erb file') working in browser console logs ?

Comment: @akshay - The model is created and transaction is committed however the js does not seem to refresh the partials in `projects/show.html.erb` file. In the rails server I am getting `Processing by ProjectMessagesController#create as JS` and `Rendered project_messages/create.js.erb (3.4ms)`

Comment: if your create.js.erb is rendering than it must append message in div with id "project_message" meanwhile I didn't find any div with id="project_message" in your code

Comment: I suggest to add id="project_message" in div class="au-message-list" in your projects/show.html.erb

Comment: @akshay - thanks for your help! I added `<div class="au-message-list" id="project_message">` but it didn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using Rails 5

remove `remote: true` and `local: true` from your code

read about this in [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements)

and make sure that you a html element with id = `project_message`

your code is `$("#project_message").append("<%= j render(@project_message) %>");`

so check your HTML code , is there any element with ID like that

Comment: thank you! I tried removing `remote: true` and `local: true` and adding `project_message` id to the project/show.html.erb with `<div class="au-message-list" id="project_message">`but it still isnt refreshing the partial list unfortunately!

Comment: it's better to paste your code in gist.github.com, and indent your code properly, so we can check easily

Answer (score 0):

you can use traditional form_for http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements

update below code in your views
`<%= form_for project_message, :remote => true do |form| %>`

and make sure that you a html element with id like `<div class="au-message-list" id="project_message">`

Comment: thanks! I tried `<div class="au-message-list" id="project_message">` with `<%= form_for project_message, :remote => true do |form| %>` but no luck - ill keep trying!

Comment: @EvaB11open javascript console on browser and tell me what logs you can see?So that I can help you.